# Drawing separated dashed/filled rectangles (sub-tables) within a tabular environment

Tags: tables, boxes, punctuation

I need to draw a table that looks like the following one.
[image]

Thickness is not important here contrary to the grouping and shading of symbols in rectangular sub-tables within the main tabular environment.

Would it be possible to do this using for instance \tcolorbox{} to fill the dashed boxes? How?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @ashryster What is the use of this notation ? Is it for logic boolean tables ?

Answer (score 5):

With a `TiKZ matrix` is not difficult to do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=1mm, row sep=1mm] {
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\};

\draw[ultra thick] (A.south west)--([yshift=2mm]A.north west) coordinate (Ann);
\draw[ultra thick] ([xshift=-2mm]A.north west) coordinate (Aww)--(A.north east);
\path (A-2-3) -- coordinate (aux) (A-3-4);
\draw (aux|-A.south)--(aux|-Ann);
\draw (aux)--(aux-|Aww);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (A-1-2.north west) rectangle (A-1-2.south east);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (A-1-5.north west) rectangle (A-1-6.south east);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (A-2-7.north west) rectangle (A-2-8.south east);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (A-4-2.north west) rectangle (A-5-2.south east);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (A-4-5.north west) rectangle (A-5-6.south east);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (A-5-7.north west) rectangle (A-5-8.south east);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just one thing off -- the shadings on the leftmost four boxes should be oriented from northwest to southeast; all of these are now southwest to northeast.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Rectified. Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution with pstricks:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\newcommand\tleft[1]{\pnode[-1.2ex, 2.5ex]{t#1}}
\newcommand\bright[1]{\pnode[1.2ex, -1.2ex]{b#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ %
\begin{postscript}
\psset{fillstyle=vlines,  hatchwidth=0.3pt,  hatchcolor=IndianRed3}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}\renewcommand\arraycolsep{8pt}
\begin{array}{cV{8}*{3}{c}|*{5}{c}}
&  &  & \\[-2ex]
\hlineB{8}
& 0 & \tleft{1}1 \bright{1} & 1 & 0 & \tleft{3} 1 & 1 \bright{3} & 0 & 1 \\%
& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \tleft{5} 1 & 1 \bright{5} \\%
\cline{1-4}
& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0  \\%
& 0 &  \tleft{2} 1 & 0 & 0 & \tleft{4} 1 & 1  &  0 & 0 \\%
& 1 & 1 \bright{2} & 0 & 0 &  1 & 1 \bright{4} & \tleft{6}  1 & 1 \bright{6}
\end{array}%
\psset{linecolor=IndianRed3, linejoin=1}
\multido{\i=1+1}{6}{ \psframe(t\i)(b\i)}
\end{postscript}%
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please check the orientation of the shadings.  the two boxes on the right should have them headed downward from right to left.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I guess I uploaded an initial version. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz. I have drawn some hatches in blue to show that are drawn *under* the coefficients of the matrix (as expected).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,patterns}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray} [rules/width=2pt] {c|cccccccc}
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \begin{tikzpicture} [inner sep = 1pt]
    \begin{scope} [every node/.style = {draw,pattern = north west lines}]
      \node [fit = (2-3)] {} ; 
      \node [fit = (5-3) (6-3)] {} ;
      \node [fit = (2-6) (2-7)] {} ;
      \node [fit = (5-6) (6-7)] {} ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [every node/.style = {draw,pattern color=blue, pattern = north east lines}]
      \node [fit = (3-8) (3-9)] {} ; 
      \node [fit = (6-8) (6-9)] {} ; 
    \end{scope}
    \draw (1-|5) -- (last-|5) (4-|1) -- (4-|5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
\\
\hline 
\hspace*{2mm}
& 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: A clean code. I definitely like `nicematrix` !